# Why do "lea..and..push" assembly codes frequently come up at the beginning of a function?

Tags: linux, x86, reverse-engineering, 32-bit

I realized when I am looking at some files through GDB, very frequently, there are these three lines of codes at the starting of the function

```
   0x08048548 <+0>:     lea    ecx,[esp+0x4]
   0x0804854c <+4>:     and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x0804854f <+7>:     push   DWORD PTR [ecx-0x4]
```

I usually ignored them because right after those three lines stack frame gets created which is how functions usually start.

Thank you.

Comment: I think it's adjusting the stack pointer to 16-byte alignment.

Comment: Hello Barmar, thank you for your reply. But why would the program be needing to adjust the stack pointer to 16-byte alignment?

Comment: At the start of a function or more specifically at the start of main? The code is part of the prologue code you'd see that aligns the stack inside`main` on a 16-byte boundary. It is done so because proper alignment is needed for the System V 32-bit ABI that modern Linux uses.

Comment: Hello Michael, thanks for the reply. Yes, it appears at the starting of the main function. So basically what the codes are doing is that they are getting ready to use the stack and the registers. Am I correct?

Comment: No this code specifically is intended to align the stack on a 16-byte boundary. not initialize the registers. It effectively gets the address of the current return address, rounds the stack down to nearest 16 byte aligned boundary and then pushes a copy of the return address on the stack to look like a proper function stack frame. Usually after that a `push ebp` is done as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing this up Michael!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is aligning the stack pointer to a 16-byte boundary, because sometimes (for SSE) the CPU needs 16 byte alignment of data.

A good compiler will examine the call graph (figure out what calls what), and will decide that:

- the function doesn't need stack alignment itself and doesn't call other functions that need stack alignment; and therefore no stack alignment is needed
- all of the function's callers used an aligned stack, and therefore either:

  - the function only needs a fixed adjustment to re-establish the pre-existing alignment, like `sub esp, 8` (which could be merged with any code that reserves stack space for local variables)
  - the data that actually needs 16 byte alignment can be given 16 byte alignment without aligning the stack itself
- none of the above can be proven to be true, so the function has to assume "worst case" and enforce alignment itself (e.g. the instructions you've seen at the start of the function)

Of course for a good compiler, the last case (where the code you've shown is needed) is extremely rare.

However; most compilers can't be good because they're not able to see the whole program (if the program is split into multiple object files that are compiled separately, then the compiler can only see a fraction of the program at a time). They can't figure out much/any of the call graph, so the last case (where the code you've shown is needed) becomes very common. To solve this you need "link time code generation", but often people don't bother.

*Note: For AVX2 you want 32 byte alignment, for AVX512 you want 64 byte alignment, and for some things (to avoid false sharing in heavily threaded code) you might want "cache line size alignment" (typically also 64 byte alignment). This makes the "examine call graph to determine what alignment is actually needed" algorithm a little more complicated than what I described.*